# In Android, Can't observe the Progress of Image uploading in Cloudinary

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, cloudinary

I want to show the progress of Image uploading in a circular progresbar outside a Image in Jetpack. I convert the callback class to asynchronous.But the problem is no progress is observed in Fragment where I observe it.

Here is the code I tried.

`CloudinaryImageUploadCallback.kt`

```
import com.cloudinary.android.callback.ErrorInfo
import com.cloudinary.android.callback.UploadCallback

class CloudinaryImageUploadCallback(
    private val progressChangedListener: (Int) -> Unit,
    private val successEventListener: (String) -> Unit,
    private val errorEventListener: (String) -> Unit
) : UploadCallback {

    override fun onStart(requestId: String) { }

    override fun onProgress(requestId: String, bytes: Long, totalBytes: Long) {
        progressChangedListener(((bytes * 100) / totalBytes).toInt())
    }

    override fun onSuccess(requestId: String, resultData: Map<*, *>?) {
        resultData?.let {
            for ((key, value) in it) {
                if (key == "url") {
                    successEventListener(value.toString())
                    return@let
                }
            }
        }
        errorEventListener("URL not found in resultData")
    }

    override fun onError(requestId: String, error: ErrorInfo) {
        errorEventListener(error.description)
    }

    override fun onReschedule(requestId: String, error: ErrorInfo) {
        errorEventListener(error.description)
    }
}
```

`ImageUploadResult.kt`

```
sealed class ImageUploadResult<out T : Any> {
    data class Progress(val percentage: Int) : ImageUploadResult<Nothing>()
    data class Success<out T : Any>(val data: T) : ImageUploadResult<T>()
    data class Error(val exception: Exception) : ImageUploadResult<Nothing>()
}
```

`CloudinaryDataSource.kt`

```
import android.net.Uri
import android.util.Log
import com.cloudinary.android.MediaManager
import kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuation
import kotlinx.coroutines.suspendCancellableCoroutine
import javax.inject.Inject
import kotlin.coroutines.Continuation
import kotlin.coroutines.resume
import kotlin.coroutines.resumeWithException

class CloudinaryDataSource @Inject constructor() {

    suspend fun uploadFileToCloudinary(file: Uri): ImageUploadResult<String> {
        return suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
            val options: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
            options["folder"] = "Profile"
            options["tags"] = "profile"

            MediaManager.get()
                .upload(file)
                .options(options)
                .unsigned("cross-border-education-technologies-pte-ltd")
                .callback(
                    CloudinaryImageUploadCallback(
                        progressChangedListener = {
                            if (!continuation.isActive) {
                                ImageUploadResult.Progress(it)
                            }
                        },
                        successEventListener = {
                            if (!continuation.isActive) {
                                ImageUploadResult.Success(it)
                            }
                        },
                        errorEventListener = {
                            if (!continuation.isActive) {
                                continuation.resumeWithException(ImageUploadResult.Error(Exception(it)).exception)
                            }
                        }
                    )
                )
                .dispatch()
        }
    }

}
```

`ImageUploadRepository.kt`

```
interface ImageUploadRepository {
    suspend fun uploadFile(file: Uri): ImageUploadResult<String>
}
```

`ImageUploadRepositoryImpl.kt`

```
class ImageUploadRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val cloudinaryDataSource: CloudinaryDataSource
): ImageUploadRepository {

    override suspend fun uploadFile(file: Uri): ImageUploadResult<String> {
        return cloudinaryDataSource.uploadFileToCloudinary(file)
    }

}
```

`UploadProfileImageToCloudinaryUseCase.kt`

```
class UploadProfileImageToCloudinaryUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val imageUploadRepository: ImageUploadRepository
) {

    operator fun invoke(file: Uri): Flow<ImageUploadResult<String>> = flow {
        try {
            emit(imageUploadRepository.uploadFile(file))
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            emit(ImageUploadResult.Error(e))
        }
    }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)

}
```

`ProfileEditViewModel.kt`

```
@HiltViewModel
class ProfileEditViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val uploadProfileImageToCloudinaryUseCase: UploadProfileImageToCloudinaryUseCase
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _uploadProgressState = MutableStateFlow(0)
    val uploadProgressState: StateFlow<Int> = _uploadProgressState.asStateFlow()

    fun uploadImageToCloudinary(file: Uri) {
        uploadProfileImageToCloudinaryUseCase.invoke(file)
            .onStart {  }
            .onCompletion {  }
            .onEach { result ->
                when (result) {
                    is Progress -> _uploadProgressState.value = result.percentage
                    is Success -> uploadProfilePicture(result.data)
                    else -> {}
                }
            }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }
}
```